# swift - update directions when user moves

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, apple-maps

I am writing an app where a user can select a location and then it will display the directions to it on the map. This functionality works fine, however I need the route to update on the map as the user moves. Currently I am using the `didupdatelocations` method and creating a new direction line from the new user location, however this results in the polyline being completely redrawn. I am trying to find a way to update the directions as the user moves similar to how apple maps/google maps does this. I do not want to use the navigation window if possible.

I am using the Apple mapKit.

i have looked for similar problems [this one with google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552713/swift-google-maps-update-directions-from-current-location) but there have been no replies.

I have seen another example (sorry cannot find link again) which makes an array of all the coordinates in the polyline although im not sure where i would use this or how to use this to slice or remove the unwanted part of the polyline.

At the moment my code does remove all overlays when a new direction is called, but if the overlays are not removed then I will end up with loads of lines on the map. I have tested removing the first polyline after the second polyline is created but that doesn't seem a very efficient way of dealing with this.

would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: don't know if you can/want to use some third party sdk, but if so, my suggestion is to have a look on Mapbox turn by turn nav.

Comment: I would prefer not to but will look into that, thank you for the advice.

At the moment I have getting a new set of directions when didUpdateLocations is called, and then removing the old overlay after the new one has been added. Doesnt seem like best solution.